# How do I use RxJS to process hundreds of requests without crashing?

Tags: angular, rxjs, concatenation

I need to process 400+ employee objects which involves calling an observable service method for each one.

I need to know when all employees have been processed, and, I need to find a way of doing this which does not cause my client or server to be overloaded with simultaneous requests - that's what's happening at the moment.

I want to gather the results of each employee's processing into to an array from which I can further work with the data (I'm creating an export file).

I have been trying RxJS ***concat*** and ***forkjoin*** but I still seem to have 400+ tasks all firing off at the same time.

[I read this page](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/concat.html) about ***concat*** which suggests that the processing is handled one-at-a-time, (like a queue at an ATM) but I'm not convinced - again my browser hung and the number of network requests suggested all-at-the-same-time to me.

If I could get the code to process one employee at a time and finish before handling the next employee in the list, that would be just fine.

```
processEmployees(): AsyncSubject<boolean> {
    let employeesProcessed: AsyncSubject<boolean> = new AsyncSubject<boolean>();
    let listOfProcessesToRun = [];

    this.employeeProfilesList.forEach(
        (employeeProfile: EmployeeProfile) => {
            listOfProcessesToRun.push(
                this.annualLeaveCalculationService.startProcess(employeeProfile, this.yearToProcess).delay(2000)
            );
        }
    )

    Observable.concat(listOfProcessesToRun)
        .finally(() => {
        })
        .subscribe(
        (calculationResults: AnnualLeaveCalculationResults) => {
            this.calculationResults.push(calculationResults);
            employeesProcessed.complete();
        },
        error => {
        });

    return employeesProcessed;
}
```

I have tried using ***Observable.forkjoin*** to process an array of observables, but I believe that the requests are handled in parallel, and that resulted in my machine hanging due to there being some 400 employees to process.

I have considered a nested solution, e.g.

```
processemployee(X) {
    doServiceCall(this.employees[x])
    .subscribe( response => {
            processemployee(++x); // with a check to detect number of loops
        }
    );
}
```

but I'm not sure that's a great pattern.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [`.mergeMap`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-mergeMap) overload which takes the `concurreny` and set it to something sane (like 20req concurrent) to your service. That way you optimise for maximum throughput without swamping your server.

Comment: Ah, thanks that sounds interesting. I will attempt it now and post my results. Much appreciated!

Comment: I had to use a ***concurrent*** value of 1, otherwise I ran into some strange situations, such as the output from the outer observable appearing to be repeated, and more besides. Doubtless I need to polish-up my understanding of what mergeMap is doing. Otherwise, with a value of 1 for the concurrent parameter, it worked just as I wanted it to.

Answer (score 0):

I recently step into a sort of similar problem, if I understand correctly this one.

I had thousands of requests to process in parallel. The number was too high and the whole thing collapsed.

I was pointed then to use a combination of `bufferCount()` and `concatMap()` operators to achieve what I wanted.

- `bufferCount()` divide the original stream in chunks, all containing
  the same number of elements
- `concatMap()` elaborates the first chunk (in parallel) via a function
  passed as argument - the function returns an Observable - when the
  Observable completes, then the second chunk is taken and so on

Maybe this approach can help.